# Error after verifying a new account + pressing back

Tags: bug, user-accounts, linked-accounts

I just registered a new account on Japanese SE by signing in with my SO account. When you link an account, there's a "confirm your new account" message that pops up, and you have to click the orange button, I think it says "verify". So I clicked verify, and it worked, but I went back a page (i.e. top left corner) and clicked verify again, and it gave me an error. Nothing broke later, it just gave me a generic error screen that told me that an internal error occurred.

Just thought I'd let someone know.

Comment: *and it gave me an error.* That is not really a good problem description. Consider to add screen shots for example.

Comment: The message was something along the lines of "Oh no! There's an internal error. Don't worry though, it's not your fault." I think it's the standard error, that's why I said that.

Comment: Going "back" in the browser is notoriously flaky on SE sites and gives you all kind of surprises. If an action  changed something server-side, don't expect that change to be reflected client-side when you get a cached page from the browser. Maybe the error should say: "You already signed up" but I think this is a corner case not many users will hit, I guess just barking at the user is fine.